# onclick multiple times javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So im making a form where theres an image on an eye that should show the password when clicked and when clicked again it should hide it.
i made that when its clicked it change the src attribute of the img and change the type of input

```
if(img.src = 'images/eye1.png'){
        img.src = 'images/eye2.png';
        password.type = 'text'
}
```

and if the img.src is eye2 so after i click the first time it return back to the original

```
else if(img.src = 'images/eye2.png') {
        img.src = 'images/eye1.png';
        password.type = 'password'
    }
```

i tried with else too but it doesnt do anything after the first click and i cant find a solution.
help please :(

Comment: when comparing you need to use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not verifying any equal condition since you have to use "==" (equal) and not "=" (assignment)

```
// This line
if(img.src == 'images/eye1.png'){
    img.src = 'images/eye2.png';
    password.type = 'text';

// and this one
} else if(img.src == 'images/eye2.png') {
    img.src = 'images/eye1.png';
    password.type = 'password';
}
```

It is possible to assign a value to a variable in an if. That's why you didn't see an error. I advise you to place the variable to the right side of the ==. Because when you try to assign a value to a text, the console will display an error, because the text is not a left value

Example:

```
if('images/eye2.png' == img.src) {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: i tried that too but if i use == the button wont work, even with ===, it works only with one.

Comment: Show more of your code pls

Comment: ```function showPassword() {
    let img = document.getElementById('img')
    let password = document.getElementById('password')

    if(img.src == 'images/eye1.png'){
        img.src = 'images/eye2.png';
        password.type = 'text'
    } else if(img.src == 'images/eye2.png') {
        img.src = 'images/eye1.png';
        password.type = 'password'
    }
}

```

Comment: ```button type="submit" class="submitbtn" onclick="submit()" id="button"><p class="submittext" id="text">SUBMIT</p></button>```

Comment: Provide a testable jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4en9dqkg/2/

Comment: so as I said replacing "=" by "==" works in jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/L0hn8dr7/1/

Comment: i saw, that thing doesnt work on VS code i dont know the reason

Comment: and doesnt even work with an online website